# Hide UWP mouse cursor on program load

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, mouse

Is there a way to hide the mouse cursor in a windows store application in code so that the mouse is hidden immediately on application start?

I run the following command as my page starts and nothing happens until I physically move the mouse. As soon as I move the mouse it hides. If I don't move it it stays on screen indefinitely. As I'm displaying graphics I need to hide the mouse immediately without any input from the user.

Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = null;

Comment: Maybe you could move it programmatically with Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPosition = new Point(X, Y); ?

Comment: I've tinkered some more, moving the pointer doesn't appear to do the trick as it make the pointer appear. Setting Pointer to null at a later point than in the mainpageloaded event appears to make it function correctly.

Comment: If you find answer to your question don't forget to add it as an answer and validate it (i believe there is a two day delay before you can do this) as other people might come across this problem

Answer (score 0):

As Colin mentions in the comments the mouse pointer disappears if you hide it when the window fires the Loaded event.

```
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = null;
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPosition = new Point(42, 42);
}
```

My problem is the WebView element, it briefly flickers the mouse pointer once when moving it even with this code.